# Activate type only without knowing the namespace of the type I am trying to activate

Tags: c#, reflection, gettype

I'm not sure this is possible, and the existing answers to this question seem to imply that you need to know the namespace.

I am trying to activate a type, but would prefer to avoid specifying the Type's namespace. Is this possible? Of course I would know the Assembly ahead of time.

```
string qualifiedName = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyType)).FullName;
Type toActivate = Type.GetType("sometype, " + qulifiedName);
```

I've tried various ways, but hitting road blocks. Seems like I must know the namespace of the type. Is this true? Or am I missing something.

To recap, I have two things...

1. The name of the type, ie MyClass
2. Its executing assembl

Comment: And if there are two types with the same name in different namespaces?

Comment: In that case it would be fine to fail... but if there is only one, it should create the instance... I guess I would have to manually check every namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all types in the current application domain or executing assembly and do a `Where` to get the type you're looking for.

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(t => t.GetTypes())
```

Or

```
var types = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyType)).GetTypes()
```

Followed by:

```
var myType = types.Where(t => t.Name == nameToFind);
```

Then you can decide whether a type was found, or if multiple, which one to use.

Comment: I feel kinda silly now seeing how simple the answer is... anyway, well done sir.